# Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric. AVG Select Statment

Tags: sql, average

I am trying to average the values for a given month using the AVG function but it's throwing the `Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.` After some Googling, it looks like the common cause for this is trying to store the output of the AVG function into a variable/column that has a datatype not suitable for the incoming value. I am receiving this error just trying to `SELECT` the values.

```
--Hours (DECIMAL(18,4)), Starts (DECIMAL(18,4))
SELECT ID, Avg(Hours), Avg(Starts)
FROM MonthlyReadings
WHERE ReadingDate < '2016-03-01'
AND   ReadingDate > DATEADD(MM, -36, '2016-03-01')
AND   MONTH(ReadingDate) = 1
GROUP BY ID
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Comment: hours and starts are both `INT`?

Comment: No, they are `DECIMAL(18,4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resulting datatype is inherited from the field you're aggregating. You need a datatype large enough to hold the `SUM()` in order to calculate the `AVG()`, you should be fine with `FLOAT` or expand your `DECIMAL`:

```
SELECT ID, Avg(CAST(Hours AS FLOAT)), Avg(CAST(Starts AS FLOAT))
FROM MonthlyReadings
WHERE ReadingDate < '2016-03-01'
AND   ReadingDate > DATEADD(MM, -36, '2016-03-01')
AND   MONTH(ReadingDate) = 1
GROUP BY ID
```